# How to utilize procesbuilder to change related list

Tags: process-builder, record-type, fields, update

I have a use-case where I have several opportunities divided by 2 recordtypes. At the moment all show up in the related list on account. I have created 2 extra lookup fields from opportunity to account for the 2 opportunity recordtypes. I want to hide the standard related list of opportunity on account an use the 2 other related lists to separate the recordtypes so that related list A on account has opportunity recordtype A and related list B has opportunity recordtype B. How do I assign the different recordtypes to the different related lists with Procesbuilder.
1. Do I start from Opportunity or from Account as an object
2. How do i get to select the related list in the Proces builder? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opportunity is the record you want to trigger on. The criteria will be the record types, and the actions will be to set the appropriate lookup fields. You're not targeting a "related list", but simply the object that you wish to change. Since the change occurs on the opportunity, that's the object you need to use.

[image: Sample Process Builder]